# PowerShell master script to execute functions

Tags: powershell-ise, powershell-4.0

I have a`.ps1`file which houses 4 functions. I am not sure how to call the functions or have that script run. I need all the 4 functions to run one after the other and i believe i have tried every possible way to execute that `powershell` file, but haven't got any success so far.Can someone please help me out on how to call those functions to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undertand correctly, you can dot source your file to make your functions available.

```
. c:\path\to\core.ps1
function1 
function2
```

Comment: cheers mate. How could i be that stupid, lol i should have figured that out. But that works :)

Comment: Function F1
    {$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName compip -Credential username} Does this work? If i want to recall $sess in another function after this.

Comment: this will not work, please take a look at [the scope documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh847849.aspx)

Comment: is there no way around it?

Comment: does something like          for each ($sess in c:\file\name\target work?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. If you want to make $sess variable accessible from outside it's current scope you will have to declare it as a script variable `$script:sess=new-pssession...` ( it will be available at the script scope), or to declare it as a global var `$global:sess=new-pssession...` will be available to all scope as long as the console is running